# Is there a way to tell when the dispensers are going to dispense their item?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

If you take a look at the screenshot, you'll see liquorice dispensers in the middle. If you've  played Candy Crush before, you'll know that liquorice is annoying and serves no purpose other than to hinder you.

[image: candy crush picture]

Is it possible to tell when it going to dispense the liquorice (or whatever item the dispenser is designated to dispense such as ingredients, bombs, etc.)?  I can't distinguish if there is a pattern they follow or not. It seems to me that it is random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These dispensers usually dispense randomly as long as it is reasonable (i.e. it can't give you more than the required number), except for licorice/liquorice, which tries to dispense as much as possible, as shown in the Candy Crush wikia: "Liquorice dispensers will drop as many liquorice swirls as possible every single turn. The only way to stop them from falling is to get three candies in a row next to an already-dropped liquorice swirl."